# IMU_UM6... where to install?

Tags: ros, rosdep, stacks, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

imu_um6 is a package with no associated stack. I would like to install this in the opt/ros/fuerte stacks folder with other drivers (those drivers that come with stacks install here).

I did try creating a workspace and placing imu_um6 here but when running rosdep I get errors relating to not finding key resources in the opt/ros/fuerte location.

How do I best install imu-um6 and associated dependencies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41190/imu_um6...-where-to-install?/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2012-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well, um6 depens on rospy,geometry_msgs, sensor_msgs and tf which are already installed with fuerte distribution. Make sure that you put your imu_um6 package in your workspace directory and run rospack profile command after that compile it by make, then launch the test file. I believe that there will be no problem. I hope that this helps you

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2012-08-11**:
I followed your instructions and everything seems to work, but if the um6 is in a workspace how do I get an application like hector_slam to access the IMU data if hector_slam is in a different workspace? Should the imu_um6 driver be loaded in the hector_slam workspace?

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-08-11**:
there will be no difference because your package path contains both your workspace and stack directory